# How to read other cells in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, manim

I am trying to write a magic function for jupyter notebook which will let me see the output of [`manim`](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim) directly within the notebook.

To achieve that I basically save the content of the cell into a temporary `.py` file and then call the `manimce` command within a subprocess with the temporary `.py` file and check the output to find the path of the video/gif created.

My question is that, let's say I've got some other variables declared in other cells (or even import statements) and I use them in the cell where my magic function is invoked. How could I also save those variables (or basically the code) from other cells in the same temporary `.py` file so that I won't get an error? Or any other way that can be achieved? Hopefully the screenshot below better explains what I am trying to ask.

[image: jupyter-notebook-screenshot]

Here is the code I've used:

```py
# manimce_magic.py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic, cell_magic, line_cell_magic
from IPython.core.magic import needs_local_scope
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import IPython.display
import os
import re

def find_path(output_string):
    output_string = output_string.decode('utf-8')
    output_string = re.sub(' ', '', ''.join(output_string.split('\n')))
    if m := re.search('(?<=Filereadyat).+(?=INFO)', output_string):
        return m.group(0)

@magics_class
class ManimceMagic(Magics):
    @needs_local_scope
    @cell_magic
    def manimce(self, line, cell, **kwargs):
        manimce_args = line.split()
        f = NamedTemporaryFile('r+', suffix='.py', delete=False)
        try:
            f.write(cell)
            f.close()

            args = ['manimce', f.name, *manimce_args]
            p = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
            output, err = p.communicate()
            path = find_path(output)
            display(IPython.display.Code(output.decode('utf-8'), language='python3'))
            display(p.returncode)
        finally:
            os.remove(f.name)

        if path:
            path = Path(path)
            relative_path = path.relative_to(Path.cwd())

            if '-i' in manimce_args:
                return IPython.display.Image(relative_path, width=854, height=480)
            else:
                return IPython.display.Video(relative_path, width=854, height=480, html_attributes='controls loop autoplay')

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.register_magics(ManimceMagic)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your specific question, but perhaps this will be helpful nonetheless.  I believe the current version of manim comes with a manim magic command already.  I have tried it and it seems to work fine.  I make it work, I first run `import jupyter_manim`, and then in a new cell, I write my program, beginning with the magic command `%%manim TestClass -p -ql`, where `TestClass` is the name of the animation I am building.  The manim output appears right there in the Jupyter notebook.